# Is it possible to pass my customView into setContentView in Android?

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-viewgroup

In my onCreate I have a layout which i want to set Dynamically

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View coachLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coach_content, null);
    LinearLayout coachLinear = (LinearLayout) coachLayout.findViewById(R.id.coachLinear);
    TextView titleView = (TextView) coachLayout.findViewById(R.id.coachTitle);
    updateTitleView(activity, widget, titleView);
```

I wish to pass my View coachlayout, into `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

However setContentView only accepts the Resource id or int. So is there anyway to pass my coachlayout into setContentView?

Thanks

Comment: "However setContentView only accepts the Resource id or int" -- no, [it also accepts a `View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)).

Comment: @CommonsWare ahh i see the overloads thank you ! However, just out of curiosity is there a way to convert View into an int?

Comment: No, sorry. You cannot create a resource at runtime.

Comment: Int is wrong. It's (a int but..) layout resource id.